# Use XPath to parse element name containing a colon

Tags: xpath

So I'm trying to parse some of the [WootAPI](http://www.woot.com/salerss.aspx) with XPath. A problem that I'm running into is that a couple of the elements have colons in their name, such as `woot:price` or `woot:condition`. Now, trying to use the XPath `//rss/channel/item/woot:price` won't grab the contents of the element `woot:price`, because of the colon, I think. What can I do to get it anyway?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The colons are because the elements have a namespace prefix and are bound to the Woot namespace.

You should read up on [XML namespaces and how they affect XPATH and XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx).

If you want to reference the Woot elements in your XPATH you will either need to:

1. Declare the Woot namespace `http://www.woot.com/` so that when you use that namespace prefix in your XPATH it will be understood.
2. Use a more generic XPATH statement that uses predicate filters that use `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` to match the element.

   - `//rss/channel/item/*[local-name()='price' and namespace-uri()='http://www.woot.com/']`

Comment: 1. Know how to do that in Java?
2. I tried using that example you provided, and it didn't work. :\

Comment: I had a mistake in the XPATH that I had provided (was missing the "h" in the woot namespace uri and didn't have the closing bracket). I've updated it. Retry.

Comment: This solution worked with only the local-name()='thing' and by NOT using the namespace-uri()='url'

Comment: Using .NET and C# I found that i had to add the namespace to the XmlDocument via XmlDocument.NamespaceTable.Add() method.  Then in each XPath query (e.g. SelectNodes()) I had to pass in the NamespaceManager object.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation?view=netframework-4.6.2#namespaces-in-xpath-expressions

Comment: With XML parsing, it is always a namespace thing. :)