# XPath query for XML node with colon in node name

Tags: xpath

What XPath query will select the `<media:thumbnail />` node in the following XML?

```
<item>
  <title>Sublime Federer crushes Wawrinka</title>
  <description>Defending champion Roger Federer cruises past Stanislas Wawrinka 6-1 6-3 6-3 to take his place in the Australian Open semi-finals.</description>
  <link>http://news.bbc.co.uk/go/rss/-/sport2/hi/tennis/9372592.stm</link>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/tennis/9372592.stm</guid>
  <pubDate>Tue, 25 Jan 2011 04:21:23 GMT</pubDate>
  <category>Tennis</category>
  <media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/50933000/jpg/_50933894_011104979-1.jpg"/>
</item>
```

The XML came from this [RSS feed](http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportonline_world_edition/front_page/rss.xml).

Comment: That "node with a colon" is a node using an **XML namespace** (defined in the <rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
 node) - you need to get a grip on what those are and how to deal with them - see http://www.intertwingly.net/stories/2002/09/09/gentleIntroductionToNamespaces.html

Comment: What programming language / system / environment are you using??

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for your quick response. I'm using c++/libxml2

Comment: I just figured I can do //@url to get all url elements

Comment: yes, selecting an attribute will work, since those are typically not in any XML namespace...; unfortunately, I'm neither fluent in C++ nor do I know libxml2 :-( so I can't really help you here. Check your documentation on how to define and use XML namespaces when selecting XML using XPath!

Comment: @marc_s: thanks so very much for your useful input.

Comment: First exact duplicate in google search [Use XPath to parse element name containing a colon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282147/use-xpath-to-parse-element-name-containing-a-colon)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**You need to learn about namespaces** and how to define/register a namespace in your XPath engine so that you can then use the associated prefix for names in that registered namespace. There are plenty of questions in the [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath) tag asking how to use names that are in a namespace -- with good answers. Search for them.

**A very rough answer** (ignoring namespaces at all) is:

```
//*[name()='media:thumbnail']
```

Comment: how to write the xpath if media:thumbnail had child element with media:image and we had to get media:image element

Comment: @bhatkrishnakishor, Use `//*[name()='media:thumbnail']/*[name() = 'media:image']`

Comment: /item/*[local-name()='thumbnail']
is what worked for me.

Comment: I'm looping a XmlNodeList but on every loop, I get the same child node which is the first one, I have no clue why this happeing

Comment: @DushyanthKandiah: Please, ask a question and provide all relevant code and data. Also, explain there what you want to select with the XPath expression.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev this line of code worked for me `*[local-name()='thumbnail']`

Comment: @DushyanthKandiah, This means that you have elements named `thumbnail` that are in more than one namespace. Generally I discourage people from using `local-name()` because they may not be aware of the different namespace issue and if they were, they would probably only want to select elements in a particular (not all) namespace.

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me is:

```
/item/*[local-name()='thumbnail']
```

Comment: While the accepted answer is a better answer in that it is more thorough and explains what is going on, this is the better answer because the solution works.

Comment: lol ya that's because I don't really understand. I just noticed local-name() in completely unrelated xpath and since name() wasn't working for me I tried local-name() and it worked. So the accepted answer is much better, in situations where name() works.

Comment: For whatever reason this did not work with .NET System.Xml namespace tools in C#.  I had to specifically add the namespace to my XmlDoc object.  By the way, the namespace it is using for "media:thumbnail" is:  xmlns: media = 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'

Answer (score 1):

If you're looping an XmlNodeList array
just use `*[local-name()='thumbnail']`