# scrapy, invalid xpath, starting position

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrapy, and I have this ridiculous html that I'm trying it on. Using the Xpath Checker firefox plugin, this is the first row in the table:

`id('page')/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[1]`

I get an error if I copy that xpath in:

```
def parse(self, response):
      hxs = HtmlXParseSelector(response)
      data = hx.select("id('page')/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[1]")
```

`raise ValueError("Invalid XPath: %s" % xpath)`

Why does it not recognize this xpath?

Also, is there a way for scrapy to grab all data from the 3rd row and onwards? The first two rows are just title and the legend.

Comment: If you could provide a link to the page you're trying to scrape, we might be able to help out. :)

Comment: Did you register the [namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817112/xpath-query-for-xml-node-with-colon-in-node-name)?

Comment: Only one advice - use Firebug or Chrome Developer not Firefox Xpath Checker

Answer (score 1):

Firefox adds an html tag "tbody", but really html can be without it. Try to get the html page with your program and see where the tag "tbody". I faced the same problem and the same in Firefox.

Comment: I had the same issue with chrome adding "tbody" to the path but scrapy does not recognize it. The solution is to just remove the "tobdy". http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/firefox.html